# Expect script SSH not successful

Tags: ssh, expect

I have made two scripts:

This one fetches IP address & Hostnames:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat ~/script/hosts.txt`
do HOSTNAME=`echo $i|awk -F: '{print $1}'`
IP=`echo $i|awk -F: '{print $2}'`
TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
~/script/expect.sh $HOSTNAME $IP
done
```

This one does SSH into the devices:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set HOSTNAME [lindex $argv 0]
set IP [lindex $argv 1]
exp_internal 1
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP
exit
```

I want to make a script to bakcup multiple device configurations.
Problem is that SSH is failing due to following errors:

```
$ ./main.sh
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.102.82.235
: Name or service not knownname 10.102.82.235
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.102.82.239
: Name or service not knownname 10.102.82.239
```

When I debug, I see the following error

```
spawn id exp4 sent <ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.102.82.235\r\r: Name or                                                          
service not known\r\r\n>
: Name or service not knownname 10.102.82.235
```

I think the issue is due to these characters: "\r\r",  "\r\r\n"
Is there any way I can filter these out?

Comment: why dont you use  tr -d '\r\r'  $IP it will strip out carriage returns

Comment: Where to put it? I am not good in programming or scripting!

Comment: You need to fix the "hosts.txt" file: it contains DOS `\r\n` line endings. Use `dos2unix hosts.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman you are correct. I tried to convert but after conversion still it is containing return character for next line. Is it possible to filter the input in the Expect script?

Comment: yes. `set hostname [regsub {\r$} [lindex $argv 0] ""]` and similar for `set ip ...`

Comment: I think the issue is due to fact that I am running it in Windows using Cygwin...  It is running properly in linux..  I will try to move it to linux environment..

Comment: Thank you all for your help.. The script is running perfectly in Linux. So issue was due to Cygwin or linux-windows mixed environment. There are some restrictions in the network so I am forced to run it in windows rather that linux.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but your shell script can use much improvement:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r host ip; do
    timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d %T)
    ~/script/expect.sh "$host" "$ip"
done <  ~/script/hosts.txt
```

Notes:

- don't use `` for line in `cat file` `` to read the lines of a file -- a `for` loop reads **words** from a file
- use `$(...)` for command substitution, not `` `...` `` -- improved readability, and easy to nest
- don't use `UPPERCASE_VARIABLES` -- those should be reserved for the shell's use.
- your (unused) `TIMESTAMP` variable actually contains a date, no time.
- quote your `"$variables"` unless you can explain why you want them unquoted.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.. The script is running perfectly in Linux. So issue was due to Cygwin or linux-windows mixed environment. There are some restrictions in the network so I am forced to run it in windows rather that linux.